# useParams to get the Url id and find an item via its index in react

Tags: reactjs, parameters, find, fetch-api

I have used Params to get the URL of the page that I linked to it before and it was ok to this stage, but then I can't set items accordingly.

```
const {id} = useParams();
const [item, setItem] = useState([]);

useEffect(() => {
  fetch("https://.../V1/homepage/consts_list_homepage")
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((data) => {
      console.log(data);
      const selectedItem = data.data.find((item,index) => index + 1 === id);
      setItem(selectedItem);
    })
    .catch((error) => console.log(error));
}, []);
```

I should mention that as there is no id in my items data, I've used `index+1` instead of id. It rendered the id but I wondered why the item doesn't set. I receive Loading... for

```
<h2 className="drname">
                    {item ? `${item.Fname} ${item.Lname}` : "Loading..."}
                  </h2>
```

I have change the route path to "..../:id" too
I would be so thankful if you help me solve the problem

Comment: `index` argument to the `.map` callback is a number type, the route path params are ***always*** a string type, using strict equality, e.g. *`===`* will never be equal. If the `id` is the "index" into the data, then just access the array data directly.

Answer (score 0):

I would do few things here:

1 - Check that "id" really contains what it's supposed to

2 - Why are you saving an array in item instead of the element? I expect to have an item, so that you need to change several things:

```
// Item is initialized as null
const [item, setItem] = useState(null);
...
// The find method will return an array with only 1 item, so that take the first element of the array as selectedItem
const [selectedItem] = data.data.find((item,index) => index + 1 === id);
```

Answer (score 0):

The miracle of asking a question in StackOverflow. I just solved it after 2 hours of struggling. I just changed it to:

`const selectedItem = data.data[id - 1];`